# Hide a C# program from the task manager?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to hide a C# program from the Windows Task Manager?

EDIT:
Thanks for the overwhelming response! Well I didn't intend to do something spooky. Just wanted to win a bet with my friend that I can do it without him noticing. And I'm not a geek myself to be able to write a rootkit, as someone suggested though I'd love to know how to do it.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if I did, I'd be inclined to ask about your reasons for doing so before explaining just how to go about doing this.

Comment: yes, there is: don't start it

Comment: I think we all know exactly what kind of program needs to do this 
X-)

Comment: I think it's a valid and interesting question.

Comment: I can think of a few non-malicious reasons for it when it comes to monitoring computers. Is it right or correct? Probably not but it could be argued as a valid reason.

Comment: Anything could be argued, but the OP should come back and tell us if our speculations are correct.

Comment: These posts might be of use:

http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+sony+rootkit

Comment: Not everyone who buys sharp knives is a murderer.

Comment: If you need this for monitoring user activity, the legitimate solution is **don't** hide it from the task manager; just adjust permissions so that it can't be killed with anyone that's not a domain admin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide console C# application from Task Manager ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759466/is-it-possible-to-hide-console-c-application-from-task-manager)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide a process in Task Manager in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187983/how-do-i-hide-a-process-in-task-manager-in-c)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of - and there shouldn't be. The point of the task manager is to allow users to examine processes etc.

If the user should be able to do that, they should be able to find your program. If they shouldn't be poking around in Task Manager, group policy should prevent that - not your program.

Comment: fully agree. I don't see any reason why a program should achieve.

Comment: Yes, over-achieving programs are just so annoying.

Comment: They certainly are if what they're "achieving" is spamming, wiping your hard disk etc... it's perfectly reasonable to put restrictions on what programs can do.

Comment: reason: for example some anti-virus or remote application hide their tasks.

Answer (score 19):

Don't mean to zombie this but i thought i could contribute some useful information

If you want to hide a application there a two methods (that i can think of atm).

They both have their ups and downs

[1]  **SSDT Table hooking** - basically you have to set the MDL of the table to writeable, overwrite the address of `NtQuerySystemInformation` (iirc) with the address of your function and have it call the original function after filtering the results.

This method doesn't suit your needs very well because the hooking function would always need to be in memory and would involve writing a kernel mode driver.  Its a fun thing to do but debugging is a pain because an exception means a BSOD.

[2] **Direct Kernel Object Manipulation (DKOM)** - the list of processes is a doubly linked list, with a kernel mode driver you can alter the pointers of the records above and below your process to point around yours.  This still requires the use of a kernel mode driver but there are rootkits such as FU that can be easily downloaded that contain an exe and the service.  The exe could be called from inside your application as a child process (in the released version of FU, at least the one I found, there was a bug which I had to fix where if the hidden application exited the computer would BSOD, it was a trivial fix).

This will thankfully be caught by almost any decent antivirus so if you are trying to do something sneaky you'll have to learn to get around that (hint: they use a binary signature)

I have not used method 1 ever but method 2 has worked for me from a VB.Net application.

A third possible option is to just create the application as a windows service, this will show up in task manager by default but I'm willing to bet that there is a way to tell it to not show up there since there are plenty of other services which don't show up in task manager.

Hope I helped a little, my advice is that if you are interested in this kind of stuff to learn C++.

Answer (score 14):

You could make your program a service and then it would appear as "svchost". There's a little more to it than that, but that should give you a hint to go in the right direction.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any way to hide it from the task manager, but you could just disguise it by making it show up as "svchost.exe".  It'll get lumped in with all the others (there's usually several), and will become indistinguishable.

Comment: Not really - you can still see the path of the executable in Task Manager.

Comment: @frou: Yeah, but if you just name it svchost.exe and drop it somewhere underneath c:/Windows, most people would just think it's a regular windows application.

Comment: Blah - simply calling it svchost.exe is a messier/less-effective version of what samoz suggests :)

Comment: +1 - I think this is one of the more common techniques for obfuscating malware.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't hide it, but you could prevent the user from killing the process.

See [Chris Smith's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187983/how-do-i-hide-a-process-in-task-manager-in-c).