# Is there any way to hide a process from the Windows Task Manager? (<ctrl>+<alt>+<del> task list)

Tags: windows, invisible, taskmanager, processlist

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do I hide a process in Task Manager in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187983/how-do-i-hide-a-process-in-task-manager-in-c)
>   [how to create a process which is not visible in task manager or services list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918329/how-to-create-a-process-which-is-not-visible-in-task-manager-or-services-list)

I was wondering if it is possible to hide your application from the Windows Task Manager process list (preferably in C++ or VB.NET). Thanks.

Comment: @karlphillip - People here are typically ethical and avoid things like advising rootkits and such. You should not do so either. If I could downvote your comment, I would.

Comment: @Ken Well, the possible duplicate already had a reference to that magic word. But I removed it anyway.

Answer (score -3):

This is bad practice, however, if you knew your environment, you could make a guess for a name that wouldn't draw attention to itself, such as something similar to a system process

Comment: Yes, I *love* it when programs I run try to purposefully hide themselves with misleading names! Please do that.

Comment: -1. If you know it's bad practice, don't advise people to do it.

Comment: Bad practice or not, it is an answer for his question

Comment: "I need to see a doctor about my toothache." "Shoot yourself in the foot and they'll give you painkillers. – Hey! It's a valid answer to the question!" No, it isn't.

Comment: sure it is. I'm sure theres at least 1 valid situation where this would be good. Say, its your own computer and you want a process to be hidden?