# how to hide exe file in task manager?

Tags: windows, winforms

I have developed one windows application and made an exe file for that application. I have installed in my computer, right now the process name exe is showing in the task manager. How to hide my process name in task manager.

In the task manager, Process bar it will show what are all the exe running currently in the computer. I created windows application and i have installed in my computer and in the task manager process bar its showing my exe name. Now i want to hide that exe name in task manager...

Comment: Why do you want to hide your process? Can you elaborate your question? The way you have phrased it, it smells of shady practices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide a C# program from the task manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212318/hide-a-c-sharp-program-from-the-task-manager)