# how can i hide process for my application from task manager

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide a process in Task Manager in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187983/how-do-i-hide-a-process-in-task-manager-in-c)

i m developing a application for administrative purpose, it's developed completly but now i m stuck with hiding process from taskmanager, because my application monitor the users activity and send reports to admin, i have hide the application but i m not able to hide the process from task manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reliably do this. You could use a virus-like technique to hook into the Windows kernel, but your application is liable to be blocked by a virus scanner.

If you're unhappy with users closing your application, why not remove local admin rights from your users and run your app as a Windows service? Windows will then stop them from closing your app.

Comment: already this software implemented task manager hide functionality  http://www.refog.com/employee-monitoring.html

Comment: Yes, and this is usual practice for viruses too. I'd recommend not doing this, and using Windows permissions instead.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want it to run as a [windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984074(VS.71).aspx) that way it shouldn't appear as an application in task manager and in the processes it will just be one of many svchost.exe processes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service / run the application under another user. A non-administrator can not see processes belonging to other users, thus not your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that. You can rename the EXE file so that no one can know what the process is.

Comment: right click on application in task manager -> go to process

Comment: there should be some way, like kernel , but i don't know much about it...

Answer (score 0):

Read up on rootkits and techniques used to hide windows processes.
[http://www.amazon.com/Rootkits-Subverting-Windows-Greg-Hoglund/dp/0321294319](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321294319)

Also a good read from Mark Russinovich http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx